# How Can i count lengh of values in a `DataFrame` That are more or less than specific Values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Here's the example:

```py
# Suppose you have this dictionary
di = {1:0.2 , 4:0.6 , 3:0.98 , 2:0.98}

# and Now create a DataFrame from the dictionary
di = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(di,orient='index')

# Now i want to count valuse in the DataFrame that are more than 0.8 or less than 0.4
## Here is what i wrote
len(   di[di[0]>0.8 or di[0]<0.4]   )
```

But i got this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

So how can i handle it?
Thanks for Your help!

Comment: use bitwise or `|`

Comment: @AnuragDabas then it gives me This error: `TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]`

Comment: wrap both conditions into `()` ie.  `len(di[(di[0]>0.8) | (di[0]<0.4)])`

Comment: above_08 = di[di[0] > 0.8]

below_04 = di[di[0] < 0.4]


print(above_08.shape[0] + below_04.shape[0])

Comment: ( (di[0]>0.8) | (di[0]<0.4) ).sum()